# Generating word documents with small differences

Tags: microsoft-word, templates, forms

I regularly create word documents, each document consists of two main sections: (1) some basic text (e.g. date, title, to whom it is addressed) (2) then followed with some tables.

The tables are finite and standard, so there is like a total of 16 tables for example, and every time I create a document I pick some of them to include in the second section.

Of course there are minor changes in the first section as well.

Is there a way to quickly generate these documents? For example by filling the values of section (1) through some form fields and then picking the tables from a list to include them in section (2). I expect to define the tables somewhere first.

Templates are not very practical for my case, are there any other alternatives?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there was some XSL engine tuned for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Why not a mail merge?
or
Write a little Visual Basic program or Word Macros.  I think Visual Studio is free now.